# Smallest substring consisting of maximum distinct characters of a String

Tags: ruby, algorithm

Given a string, I need to find the smallest substring that contains all unique characters in the string. Here are three examples:

```
Input: "AABBBCBB"    Shortest substring: "ABBBC"    
Input: "AABBBCBBAC", Shortest substring: "BAC"        
Input: "aabcaadcc",  Shortest substring: "bcaad"
```

The unique characters in the first substring are `'A'`, `'B'` and `'C'`. The substrings that contain those characters are `'AABBBC'`, `'AABBBCB'`, `'AABBBCBB'`, `'ABBBC'`, `'ABBBCB'` and `'ABBBCBB'`. The shortest of these is `'ABBBC'`. If there are two or more shortest substrings any one can be returned.

Comment: I figured out what you are looking for from your code. I trust you will find my edit of your question OK.

Comment: Please read "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)"
and "[Writing The Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)". You're asking us to write code to solve your question, which is off-topic. We need to see evidence of your effort, where you researched, what you tried, why it didn't work, etc.

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

```
def doit(str)
  uniq_chars = str.each_char.uniq
  nbr_uniq_chars = uniq_chars.size
  last_idx = str.size - 1
  shortest = { idx: 0, size: str.size }
  last_start_idx = last_idx - nbr_uniq_chars + 1
  (0..last_start_idx).each do |start_idx|
    first_end_idx = start_idx + nbr_uniq_chars - 1
    last_end_idx = start_idx + shortest[:size] - 1
    (first_end_idx..last_end_idx).each do |end_idx|
      if (uniq_chars - str[start_idx..end_idx].chars).empty?
        shortest = { idx: start_idx,
                     size: end_idx - start_idx + 1 }
        break
      end
    end
  end
  str[shortest[:idx], shortest[:size]]
end
```

**Examples**

```
doit "AABBBCBB"   #=> "ABBBC" 
doit "AABBBCBBAC" #=> "BAC" 
doit "aabcaadcc"  #=> "bcaad"
```

**Explanation**

Suppose:

```
str = "AABBBCBB"
```

The steps are as follows.

```
uniq_chars = str.each_char.uniq
  #=> ["A", "B", "C"] 
nbr_uniq_chars = uniq_chars.size
  #=> 3 
last_idx = str.size - 1
  #=> 7 
shortest = { idx: 0, size: str.size }
  #=> {:idx=>0, :size=>8}
```

`shortest` describes the shortest subtring found so far. It is the substring

```
str[shortest[:idx], shortest[:size]]
```

Initially it describes the entire string. Continuing,

```
last_start_idx = last_idx - nbr_uniq_chars + 1
  #=> 5
```

I will be fixing the starting index, `start_idx`, initially at zero, and then consider all substrings that begin with that index. There is no reason to consider `start_idx > last_idx` as in that case `str[start_idx..-1].size < nbr_uniq_chars`, and therefore is not a possibility.

```
enum1 = (0..last_start_idx).each
  #=> #<Enumerator: 0..5:each> 
start_idx = enum1.next
  #=> 0 
first_end_idx = start_idx + nbr_uniq_chars - 1
  #=> 3 
last_end_idx = start_idx + shortest[:size] - 1
  #=> 7
```

```
enum2 = (first_end_idx..last_end_idx).each
  #=> #<Enumerator: 3..4:each> 
end_idx = enum2.next
  #=> 2 
a = str[start_idx..end_idx].chars
  #=> str[0..2].chars
  #=> ["A", "A", "B"] 
b = uniq_chars - a
  #=> ["A", "B", "C"] - ["A", "A", "B"] 
  #=> ["C"]
b.empty?
  #=> false, so do not update `shortest`
```

```
end_idx = enum2.next
  #=> 3 
a = str[start_idx..end_idx].chars
  #=> ["A", "A", "B", "B"] 
b = uniq_chars - a
  #=> ["C"] 
b.empty?
  #=> false, so do not update `shortest`
```

```
end_idx = enum2.next
  #=> 4 
a = str[start_idx..end_idx].chars
  #=> ["A", "A", "B", "B", "B"] 
b = uniq_chars - a
  #=> ["C"] 
b.empty?
  #=> false, so do not update `shortest`
```

```
end_idx = enum2.next
  #=> 5 
a = str[start_idx..end_idx].chars
  #=> ["A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C"] 
b = uniq_chars - a
  #=> [] 
b.empty?
  #=> true
```

We now have found a substring that contains all unique characters in the string, but more than that we know that it is shorter than the previous shortest substring. (No need to test!) Therefore, we update `shortest`:

```
shortest = { idx: start_idx, size: end_idx - start_idx + 1 }
  #=> {:idx=>0, :size=>6}
```

which describes the substring:

```
str[shortest[:idx], shortest[:size]]
  #=> "AABBBC"
```

We no longer need to execute `end_idx = enum2.next` for this value of `start_idx` because we know that the associated substring would begin with the string just identified, and therefore would have all unique characters in `str` but would be longer than the substring just found. We therefore execute:

```
break
```

terminating the inner loop. The next step is to generate the second element of `enum1` and go from there:

```
start_idx = enum1.next
  #=> 1 
first_end_idx = start_idx + nbr_uniq_chars - 1
  #=> 3 
last_end_idx = start_idx + shortest[:size] - 1
  #=> 6
```

This will result in `shortest` being updated (for the last time) to:

```
shortest
  #=> { idx: 1, size: 5 }
```

The remaining calculations are similar.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this algoritm with below approach.

```
def max_distinct_char(str)
  str.chars.uniq.count
end

def smallest_subset_str(str)
  str_length = str.length
  max_distinct = max_distinct_char(str)

  min_str_len = str_length

  for j in (0..str_length)
    for k in (0..str_length)
      sub_str = str[j..k]
      sub_str_length = sub_str.length
      sub_distinct_char_length = max_distinct_char(sub_str)

      if (sub_str_length < min_str_len && max_distinct == sub_distinct_char_length)
        min_str_len = sub_str_length
        sub_string = sub_str
      end
    end
  end
  sub_string
end
```

Using the above methods, we can get results as

```
smallest_subset_str "AABBBCBB"   #=> "ABBBC" 
smallest_subset_str "AABBBCBBAC" #=> "BAC" 
smallest_subset_str "aabcaadcc"  #=> "bcaad"
```

Comment: When you say "tried", does that mean this does not work?  If so, why is it posted as an answer?

Comment: This does work!, but it means there might be better answer too.

Comment: There might be, but a) that wasn't your question and b) SO isn't the forum for such questions (try CodeReview instead).

Comment: I see the solution in different other lang on geeksforgeeks.org, but want it in ruby way. Tried on it and solved it.

Comment: SO isn't a blog.

Comment: Please do not add answers unless you intend to select your answer as the appropriate solution to the question. Doing so only confuses others searching for a solution to the same question.